# User profile lost on Windows XP - recurring problem

Tags: windows-xp, profile

Yesterday on of my users reported that when he logged in he got an error stating "Windows cannot load the locally stored profile." He was able to log in to a blank profile, which we then configured for him to use. Today the exact same thing happened again.

How to I permanently fix this problem? This is a local profile on Windows XP. Our domain controller is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: I'd like to know too, it's happened to me with the same scenario, Server 2003 and an XP machine.

Answer (score 3):

Does anything show up in the Windows Event log for when the user logged out yesterday (after you restored his profile), or today (when he got the new profile)?

Does the machine have [UPHClean.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1B286E6D-8912-4E18-B570-42470E2F3582&displaylang=en) installed? UPHClean will help processes unhook from the registry on logoff, and add useful entries to the event log. These entries may help you troubleshoot what is causing the profile corruption.

You should also try running chkdsk, it's possible data corruption is caused by a problem with the hard drive.

Comment: I'll second this.  Does this issue occur after a full reboot, or a logout then login process?

Comment: Me too.  Either a registry issue, hard drive failure, or a hard drive failure where the registry is...  Any way you look at it, it's not good...

Answer (score 1):

MS has this to say about it. I'm afraid there is no permanent fix.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812339

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to deal with this.  The first is go into the user profile and delete the file ntuser.dat  This will cause it to be rebuilt but has a relativly low chance of success. Only occasionally have I been able to recover with this method.

The other is to copy out their files (desktop/favorites/mydocuments and then delete their profile entirely.  Windows will create a new profile for them then you can copy the users files back in.